# touchesBegan only fired within 768x768 pixel rectangle

Tags: ios, touch, ogre

I'm seeing weird behaviour with my iPad app on both simulator (5.1 and 6.0) and my device (iPad2 running iOS6.0). Whichever orientation the app starts in, `touchesBegan` is only fired for new touches in the region (0,0) - (767,767) - in portrait mode the bottom of the screen doesn't respond, in landscape the right side.
However, `touchesMoved` & `touchesEnded` work on the whole display - if I touch and drag to the 'broken' region, the touch release event is received.

I further noted that while on the iOS *6* simulator my app *looks* right even though it doesn't work right, on the iOS 5.1 simulator the rendering was also a bit messed up initially too:
[image: Initially starting in landscape]
[image: Initially starting in portrait]

The whole display should be grey and that box with sliders in the bottom-right corner. Again, 768 seems the magic value here. Rotating a couple of times fixes this render issue but not the input issue... start in portrait mode and rotate 180 degrees and it now looks right but the top stops responding rather than the bottom.

There is a 3rd-partly library being used here, so my main question is **what might cause this kind of problem, what should be I be looking for?** I'm also curious as to why the two simulators give different results

Answer (score 0):

If you're `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` all are looking for a location within your `self.view`, then you might not be in the correct frame area for the touches to be received. I just had a similar problem and I explicitly changed the size of the frame using:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,1536);
```

since my game is two screens tall. After readjusting the frame size, `touchesBegan` was working fine. Hopefully this helps!